# Laravel nested dependency injection - Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached

Tags: laravel, dependency-injection

Here is an example:

Today I came up to one condition where I required to call some function from ServiceA to ServiceB but again the same was required other way around. Is it something wrong with Laravel or am I doing some bad practice with Dependency Injection?

I've added a sample example that is somehow similar to my actual code base. Please kindly reply if there is something I'm missing.

Thanks!

**Controller:**

```
class ExampleController extends Controller
{

    private $serviceA;
    private $serviceB;

    public function __construct(
        ServiceA $serviceA,
        ServiceB $serviceB
    )
    {
        $this->serviceA = $serviceA;
        $this->serviceB = $serviceB;
    }
}
```

**ServiceA:**

```
class ServiceA
{

    private $serviceB;

    public function __construct(ServiceB $serviceB)
    {
        $this->serviceB = $serviceB;
    }
}
```

**ServiceB:**

```
class ServiceB
{
    private $serviceA;

    public function __construct(ServiceA $serviceA)
    {
        $this->serviceA = $serviceA;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the Laravel container is used to create new instances of an object, it inspects the dependencies of those objects and either injects bound instances from the container or news up new instances if it can.

In this case, when Laravel attempts to create a new instance of your controller, it will see that it needs ServiceA. If ServiceA is not bound in the container, it will attempt to create a new instance. So, it will inspect the dependencies of ServiceA, and see that it needs ServiceB. If ServiceB is not bound in the container, it will attempt to create a new instance. So, it will inspect the dependencies of ServiceB, and see that it needs ServiceA. If ServiceA is not bound in the container, it will attempt to create a new instance. So, it will inspect the dependencies of ServiceA, and see that it needs ServiceB. If ServiceB is not bound in the container, it will attempt to create a new instance. So, it will inspect the dependencies of ServiceB, and see that it needs ServiceA. If ServiceA is not bound in the container, it will attempt to create a new instance... you get the point.

Usually when you have two classes that are dependencies of each other, this means that there is functionality in each that that probably belongs in a third (or fourth...) class. If you can, attempt to identify this functionality and split it out into ServiceC, which both ServiceA and ServiceB depend on, instead of each other.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking to create a separate service class too. But when I searched through internet found something like this: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/28512, is it somehow related to my question too? Sorry if it is a novice question.